# Selecting a column from a table depending on the count of another column from the same table

Tags: sql

The title sounds complicated xd couldn't put it to words more clear, so I'll try with details:

There are 3 tables

- `PRODUCT`(Num,Name)
- `LEVEL`(Num,Name)
- `RISK`(NumProduct,NumLevel)

`NumProduct` and `NumLevel` are foreign keys that references to the other tables.
the primary keys are `Num` , `Num` and `NumProduct`.

So the question is: I want to show the levels of the risks where the number of products > 10, this means any level that is repeated 10 times at least in the risk table should be selected, and the result has to show level.num, level.name and the number of products.

I hope you guys help me I'm struggling with this, thanks in advance

Edit:  this was what I tried but only on paper xd not sure if its correct

```
SELECT
  Num,
  Name,
  COUNT(NumProduct)
FROM Level,
     Risk
WHERE Level.Num = Risk.NumLevel
GROUP BY NumProduct
HAVING COUNT(NumProduct) >= 10
```

Comment: What do you have so far? You would need to use the `join` and `where` keywords.

Comment: 1) Please show sample data and expected output.  2) Tag with proper database platform.  Thanks.  FYI, This is not a 'do my homework site.'  You need to show some effort if you want help

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would go a long way towards helping us understand

Comment: @OldProgrammer its not really a homework, this is just a question i run into on an exam example what i meant by i need it for an exam is that i'm preparing for one, and i couldn't solve it, with the same data presented above, there is no database plateform just plain sql.

Comment: @JNevill not sure what to show, i found the same question presented how i did so i thought it would be enough to solve it.
basically i need to select levels of risks that have at least 10 products 
like for example if lvl1 is repeated 10 times in the risk table it should be selected

Comment: You need sql query or you can use linq too ?!

Comment: @Amourk yes i tried, but i'm having a problem with the part where you need to show the number of products for each level selected in the same command.

Select Num,Name, count(NumProduct) from Level,Risk where Level.Num = Risk.NumLevel 
group by NumProduct
Having count(NumProduct) > 10 

this was my try but not sure if its correct

Comment: @Majidkhalili sql query :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If*** I follow the question properly, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  level.num,
  level.name,
  COUNT(*)
FROM level
JOIN risk
  ON level.num = risk.numproduct
GROUP BY level.num
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10;
```

Comment: You need to include `level.num` in the `group by` otherwise that's invalid SQL

Comment: thanks i was about to edit the post with a similar answer, not sure if they are correct tho i guess i would have to test them, but i think i might just go with them, i'll wait to see other answers tho, thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name btw i think it should be Risk.NumProduct not Level.Num and should it be both in the first and secound count ? or just after having ?

Comment: I am not sure the flavor of SQL that is being used, but I use similar queries in MySQL, which produces an error when using an alias in the having clause.  In the example here, the count(*) in either case will count all rows, effectively returning `(occurances of level.name)*(occurances of risk.numlevel)`.  This may not be the desired results, but the column by which it is grouped would not cause an invalid query.

Comment: thanks, i took a look at the group by and having command and i think the correct thing to do would be similar to the answer that i have edited on the post, not sure if you are right as well tho, and still not sure if you should group by Risk.Numproduct or level.num would be the same coz of the join ?

Comment: They would be the same because of the join.  Have you tried any variation of the query?  If you don't have a database set up you can use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to run it on sample data.